# How to disable a button in Angular based on return value from a function?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to disable a button in Angular based on the return value of a function. However, I get an error saying "functionName is not a function"

This is the code I have currently:

This is in my ts file :

```
makerNotApprover(makerId: any) {
    let userId = this.window.company.iv.api.Context.getActiveUser().userid.toLowerCase();
    console.log(userId);
    return (makerId == userId);
  }
```

This is in my HTML file :

```
<button [disabled] = "makernotApprover(element.MakerId)" (click)="openMessage(element.RequestID,element.RequestStatus)" mat-menu-item>
                                    <span>Approve/Reject</span>
                                </button>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I went through the docs on how to use disabled and thought this is the right way.

Comment: maker >N< otApprover. Careful about case sensitivity.

Comment: case sensitive. always watch the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in the function name, it should be maker**N**otApprover instead of maker**n**otApprover

```
<button [disabled]="makerNotApprover(element.MakerId)" (click)="openMessage(element.RequestID,element.RequestStatus)" mat-menu-item>
                                <span>Approve/Reject</span>
                            </button>
```

Comment: As the question is subject to closure (typo), please do not answer and instead post a comment, then ask for the question to be closed through the flags.